# jquery ui draggable clone wrong position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Take a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pzT8h/5/

It works if you drag an item initially, but if you were to scroll down the page a little and then drag an item, the position will be wrong.

All I'm doing is:

```
$('li').draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
});
```

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug with jquery. But, it's been fixed now.

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9315